# removing items based on count and index

Tags: python

This is my code below, I'm trying to delete all non zero objects from the first list and there corresponding index in the second list. It is currently deleting the 0th entity on the first iteration of the loop but that's it. I'm basically asking why when r reaches 2 it's not deleting the value "2"

```
r = 1
OG = [1, 2, 3]

Pred = [0, 2, 6]

while r < 10:
    print "r: %s" %r
    print OG
    print Pred

    while OG.count(r) > 0:
        bump = OG.index(r)
        del OG[bump]
        del Pred[bump]
        print "success"

    r = r+.1
print OG
```

Resulting in

[image]

Comment: Please copy/paste output rather than send a screenshot via a third party website.

Comment: Do you care about preserving order in that second list? What do you want in the end in this example? Should it be `OG = []` and `Pred = [6]`?

Comment: I do. The order correlates to movie ratings in this example

Comment: @Jérôme actually i.stack.imgur.com is the domain that holds images uploaded through stack exchange so it isn't really a third party site, but yes it should definitely be posted as text not an image.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen you're right, I didn't realize that

Comment: the reason the original code didn't work was incrementing r by 0.1 over and over accumulated floating point stuff at lower digits: r = 2.000000000000001 when it looked like it was just 2. It's far better to do the non-zero test @timgeb used since that's what's actually desired

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm trying to delete all non zero objects from the first list and there corresponding index in the second list.

It's far easier to create two new lists and re-assign the names of the lists than to do that operation in place.

I would `zip` the lists together and loop over their items in pairs, only keeping the pairs where the first element is zero. Then transpose the result again with `zip` and re-assign the names.

I assumed your lists are guaranteed to have the same length.

```
>>> list_1 = [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3]
>>> list_2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> 
>>> list_1, list_2 = map(list, zip(*((x, y) for x, y in zip(list_1, list_2) if not x)))
>>> list_1
[0, 0, 0]
>>> list_2
[2, 4, 5]
```